# type(C).creationCode who has access to this?

Tags: solidity, bytecode, deployed-bytecode, creationcode

Who has access to this?

For example, if I call `type(SimpleStorage).creationCode`, wouldn't this cause an issue because there are a lot of `SimpleStorage`'s

How does the type() function know the specific `C`/contract I am calling without an address?

So from the Solidity Docs website

> Memory byte array that contains the creation bytecode of the contract.
> This can be used in inline assembly to build custom creation routines,
> especially by using the create2 opcode. This property can not be
> accessed in the contract itself or any derived contract. It causes the
> bytecode to be included in the bytecode of the call site and thus
> circular references like that are not possible.

So it cannot be called within the contract itself (which makes sense) and cannot be called from a contract that is made from the contract we want the `creationCode` from.

So the contract can only be called from a parent contract?

To be clear I have at least three questions

1. What if there are multiple contracts named `C`?
2. Where can I call this function?
3. What is its range of scope? What are the security considerations?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run into a situation where multiple contracts are named `C`. This language construct is compile-time (not runtime), meaning contract `C` would have to be imported in order for you to use `type(C).creationCode`, and Solidity does not allow conflicting names in the same source file.

You can call this function if:

- It is not referring to itself, i.e. in contract `C` you cannot use `type(C).creationCode`
- It is not referring to a contract that is a base of itself, i.e. if contract `C` inherits from contract `B` you cannot use `type(B).creationCode`
- It is not referring to its own contract factory, i.e. if contract `C` is created by contract `B`, then you cannot use `type(B).creationCode` in `C`

In all of these cases the usage is self-referential in some way, which is why it is disallowed.

There aren't really any security considerations I can think of, since calling e.g. `create` with the code from `type(C).creationCode` is effectively the same as `new C()`.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs that you shared, it says: "Memory byte array that contains the creation bytecode of the contract. ". This means that you are passing the current Contract code to the `type` function and it gives you the bytecode of the contract

```
    // SimpleStorage is not just the name, it is full contract code
    bytes memory bytecode = type(SimpleStorage).creationCode;
```

There might be a lot of contract named "SimpleStorage" but their code is different thus their byte code is different